# Generate sound/beep in fortran 90/95

Tags: audio, fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I need to generate a sound in fortran when my run ends.
I need something similar to "\a" or Beep(***,***) that are used in c++.

Comment: Write a 'beep' function in c++ and use it in Fortran?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding the following at the end of your program

```
print *, char(7)
```

Comment: Wow this is the best! can you explain why this works?

Comment: char(7) is the bell character.  This sounded the bell on the old teletypes.  When VDUs came along, the bell was replaced by a beep.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be a little creative you can end your program with a music file. In most c:/windows/media folders you can find a number of .wav files.
In this case I copied the tada.wav file over to the location of my executable so it can play the `tada.wav` file in the command prompt when the program ends.

If you use Intel Fortran then this implementation shall work:

```
  program zsound
  use ifport
  implicit none
  integer i
  character(100) :: musicfile

  musicfile = "tada.wav"


  !  Your Program goes here...


  ! CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE(musicfile)
  i = system(musicfile)

  end
```

Comment: Execute a .wav or .mp3 directly? Have you tested it?